# How can a JUnit 3 suite know if it's being run alone or with other suites?

Tags: eclipse, junit

I'm writing JUnit 3 test suites in Eclipse, and I would like the suite to implement extended behaviour if it's being run with a bunch of additional suites, but omit certain tests if it's being run alone.  (Obvious example: methods being tested have an annotation with a status field which will be `In_Progress` during development, but `Complete` afterwords.  A test that throws a red flag when the method is marked as `In_Progress` would be a nuisance when the developer is only testing that one class, but would be very handy when it's time to test all the classes, catching cases where the developer forgot to change the status on a completed method. Another example: some test suites exist to gather related tests into a single, easy-to-run suite.  But if we're running all tests in the entire package, then the tests in this suite will be run when Eclipse visits their class, and don't need to be run a second time in this related-tests suite. So when this suite is run together with other suites, it should be empty.)

Because these tests all inherit from a common base class, I can set a `static boolean` so I'll know when I'm initializing the second and subsequent suites.  However, the first test suite won't know if additional suites will follow it.

Is there something available in the Eclipse environment that would help to detect this case?  I've tried placing the `boolean` initialization in an empty test suite that I intended to be run first, but in Eclipse the suites are not necessarily run in alphabetical order.  (We run these tests all together by selecting the package that contains them all and choosing `Run -> Run As -> JUnit Test` (or keystrokes or mouse-clicks to the same effect).)

To recap: the second and subsequent suites can detect that they are in a multi-suite run, but is there some way for the first suite to also figure this out?  Or alternatively, can I somehow get Eclipse to always run the tests in alphabetical order, i.e. my chosen configuration suite before all of the others?

Comment: I thought there might be some difference in the stack between suites run individually and suites run as part of an entire package.  However, the stack traces are indistinguishable.

Comment: I dug around in the source code of the JUnit test runners in Eclipse, hoping that there would be some hint in some static variable that could be dug out and read using Reflection.  However, they are written too cleanly, and every hint about how many test suites are being run is hidden within instances.  AFAIK, there's no way to get an instance that appears in my call stack.  There should be only one `RemoteTestRunner` instance in this VM: how can I access it?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see the JUnit spec extended to provide an easy answer to this question.  However, for now I am able to use the following hack: When Eclipse (3.4 era, RSA/RAD 7.5.5) runs all the tests in a package, it passes to the test runner a text file listing, one per line, the classes to be tested.  The text file is in the system temp directory and is named `testNamesXXXX.txt`, where `XXXX` appears to be a randomly-generated large number.

If, when my test suite starts running, such a file exists and is less than about 2 seconds old, I can conclude that we're running as part of a multi-suite run.  If all such files are older than about two seconds, I can conclude that we're running only the instant suite.

Here's code that performs the check:

```
import static java.lang.System.getProperty;

private static boolean          multiSuite = false;
private static final long       START_TIME = new Date().getTime();
private static final FileFilter TEST_NAMES = new FileFilter() {
  @Override
  public boolean accept(File f) {
    final String n = f.getName();
    return START_TIME - f.lastModified() < 2000 && // two seconds, tweak to suit
           n.endsWith(".txt")                   &&
           n.startsWith("testNames");
  }
};
private static final String     TMP_DIR    = getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

private static boolean isMultiSuite() {
  if (multiSuite)
    return true;

  if (0 < new File(TMP_DIR).listFiles(TEST_NAMES))
    return multiSuite = true; // single-equals save value and return

  return false;
}
```

If I needed more certainty, I could also open the file and validate that it a) has more than one line (class) listed and b) that the name of this testsuite class is one of the lines in the file.

Comment: It might be possible to eek out a few more CPU cycles by having the `accept()` method cache its answer and return immediately when it knows that a matching file has already been found.  However, there's a reasonable chance that the file we want will be at or near the end of the list.   Hmmm . . .